# How do you hide the subfolder using a htaccess file?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am aware that this question has already asked in one way or another, but nor the question description nor the answers were working/satisfactory. So I try to explain the issue as clearly as possible.

**SAMPLE FOLDER STRUCTURE**

```
.htaccess
index.php
[subfolder-dog]
---- index.php
---- image.jpg
---- [animals]
--------- index.php
--------- cat.jpg
--------- dog.jpg
--------- frog.jpg
```

**SAMPLE DOMAIN**

- www.dog.com

**INTENSION**

Guest visiting the website at www.dog.com, should be presented with the subfolder content without ever showing the subfolder in the URL. To make this more clear. `http://www.dog.com/image.jpg` should show the image and keep that in the URL, not that suddenly it will show `http://www.dog.com/subfolder-dog/image.jpg`.

**HTACCESS (SO FAR)**

```
# Turn on Apache mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteBase /

# IF THE HOST COMES FROM THE DOMAIN WWW.DOG.COM
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.dog.com$ [NC]

# AND IF THE REQUESTED URL DOES NOT ALREADY CONTAIN THE SUBFOLDER-DOG
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder-dog/.*$ [NC]

# REWRITE BY PREPENDING EVERY REQUEST WITH SUBFOLDER-DOG
RewriteRule (.*) subfolder-dog/$1 [L]
```

**RESULT**

At first sight, this will work as expected.

- http://www.dog.com - *Works and shows the index.php within [subfolder-dog]*
- http://www.dog.com/image.jpg - *Works and shows the image within [subfolder-dog]*
- http://www.dog.com/animals/frog.jpg - *Works and shows the image within [subfolder-dog/animals]*
- http://www.dog.com/animals/ - *Works and shows the index.php within [subfolder-dog/animals]*

The big problem only occurs on directories without trailing slashes.

- http://www.dog.com/animals - *WRONG the URL in the address bar becomes http://www.dog.com/subfolder-dog/animals. For some unpredictable reason now the subfolder is no longer hidden in the addressbar*

This wil become extremely annoying when you try and install WordPress! When putting all the WordPress files within the `subfolder-dog` folder and going to http://www.dog.com all seems normal. When clicking on "Create configuration file" button, the address bar now says http://www.dog.com/subfolder-dog/wp-admin/setup-config.php. When you correct the URL by removing the subfolder from the URL it requests a file again and it works again.

I've been stuck on this issue for a week now, hopefully someone can shine a light on this subject. It's starting to make me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ subfolder-dog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subfolder-dog/$1
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Add trailing slash if path does not contain a period or end with a slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.|/$)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yoursite.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

#Change http://yoursite.com to http://www.yoursite.com (Optional)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#Rewrites http://www.yoursite.com/subdir to http://www.yoursite.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdir/$1 [L]
```

Hope this help you!!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am going to check it out right now. Hold on.

Comment: Nope, the same bug occurs. Check the addressable when visiting http://www.shishaxite.com/comingsoon (without trailing slash)

Comment: Its working on my local machine and this work for single subfolder only

Comment: I am also using a single subfolder. I am going to try your approach on a different hosting environment. See what happens. So you say when you are not using a trailing slash you won't see the subfolder appear?

Comment: Actually when I used the trailing slash it is working. Just try removing the trailing slash from second line of htaccess not sure it will work. Even though let see whats the outcome if we do so.

Comment: Got a negative response from three complete different hosting companies. If you add a trailing slash, yes it works, if you remove the trailing slash at a subdirectory it will somehow add the subfolder to the URL.

Comment: I removed the slash in the second line as you proposed. Funny thing, with the trailing slash I got an internal error, remove the trailing slash will load the page but again with the subfolder in its url.

Comment: check this code:  

RewriteBase /

# Add trailing slash if path does not contain a period or end with a slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.|/$)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yoursite.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

#Change http://yoursite.com to http://www.yoursite.com (Optional)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#Rewrites http://www.yoursite.com/subdir to http://www.yoursite.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdir/$1 [L]

Comment: subdir is your subdirectory

Comment: I am checking it right now, thanks for your help so far. Google so much the past week my head hurts.

Comment: At first appearance the code (you missed Rewrite On at the beginning). Seems to work, but I had it working with appending a trailing slash earlier. But now the big test... I reuploaded the WordPress files in the subfolder. Wish me luck.

Comment: Best of luck. Hope it does :)

Comment: Argh! Negative! So to speak in the example terms. The animals folder wasn't working (perhaps htaccess cache thing?) so I created an insects folder and it all seemed to work. So I uploaded the raw WordPress files and went to the domain, it silently forwarded me to the WordPress files, but as soon as I press the button, the subfolder was shown again. How weird is that?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54994/discussion-between-rahul-balakrishna-and-mark).